# move hdd with OS to new computer

Tags: hard-drive

I want to move a sata drive with freebsd already installed to a different computer with different processor, different memory, and then I want to boot from the transplanted drive.  Is this possible?

Comment: Depending on how different your hardware configurations are, this may or may not work. The only sure way to know is to try it -- if something goes wrong the worst you'll have to do is reinstall the OS.

Comment: About which system are you speaking?

Comment: If you have a modern linux kernel generally it works just fine.  What is the result of **uname -r**?

Answer (score 0):

Since Processor and Motherboard are different so you have to reinstall the OS again to boot from HDD so that proper driver for CPU and Motherboard could load.

Comment: Not necessarily and not so fast: you should know at least from which processor he starts and to which processors he will arrive. :-)